# CatBoostError-All train targets are equal

Tags: catboost

I am trying to do multi output regression analysis in Catboost. Size of the matrices are:

```
x_train=(60,20)
y_train=(60,17657)
x_test=(15,20)
y_test=(15,17657)
```

Relevant code is below:

```
cat_model=CatBoostRegressor(loss_function="MultiRMSE",n_estimators=5,max_depth=4,
eval_metric="Mult 
iRMSE").fit(x_train,y_train,                                                                                         
eval_set=(x_test,y_test)
)
```

And it returns an error message as "All train targets are equal". Can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For one of the targets, all values must be equal to 0. That's why it throws an error.